# DevExtreme npm module Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dxButton is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm, webpack, devextreme

Following the suggested usage of DevExtreme npm from their page https://www.npmjs.com/package/devextreme

```
var $ = require('jquery');
require('devextreme/ui/button');
var dialog = require('devextreme/ui/dialog');

$("#myButton").dxButton({
    text: "Say hello",
    onClick: function() {
        dialog.alert('Hello world!', '', false);
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="myButton"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Results in browser error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dxButton is not a function

Checking the browser console and jQuery and $ are initialized properly but $(...).dxButton is not. 
I also stepped through DX button.js and it seems to initialized as well (however this is on a local variable $)

BTW: this is also the webpack config:

```
{
  "name": "devextreme-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "TBS",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "devextreme": "^17.2.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^1.13.1"
  },
  "author": "anonymouse",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of searching and debugging I ran into one of the "breaking changes" on release site

> BC4148 - The jQuery integration module should now be imported manually
>   when using the modular approach

What this means is that you also have to add following to your code to fix jQuery error:

```
import 'devextreme/integration/jquery';
```

*(Too bad they don't mention this in their example main npm page.)*